# Xamarin iOS: BarTintColor not working in iOS 15

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios15, bartintcolor

I came across a similar issue in this [post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420).

I tried to convert iOS native code into Xamarin.iOS C#.

**iOS Native Code:**

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = <your tint color>
navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance
```

**my own code for Xamarin.iOS C#**

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(15, 0))
{
    var appearance = new UITabBarAppearance();
    appearance.ConfigureWithOpaqueBackground();
    appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB((float)rgbColorBackground.R, (float)rgbColorBackground.G, (float)rgbColorBackground.B);
    this.TabBarController.TabBar.StandardAppearance = appearance;
}
else
     TabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB((float)rgbColorBackground.R, (float)rgbColorBackground.G, (float)rgbColorBackground.B);
```

However, there is no reference to "scrollEdgeAppearance" in Xamarin.iOS C#, and it seems important to add this to solve the issue. I'd be grateful if someone can give me some advice or  point out my mistakes.

Comment: I suggest, for now, you switch versions(12 or 13) and report the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to solve transparent tabbar in IOS 15.

public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)

// Color of the selected tab icon:
UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor =    AppColors.Primary500Color.ToUIColor();
UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = AppColors.WhiteColor.ToUIColor();
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(15, 0))
UITabBar.Appearance.ScrollEdgeAppearance = new UITabBar().StandardAppearance;

Regards Joacim